# Magento: Email template crashes new template form

Tags: zend-framework, magento

I have a module that I'm trying to use with an email template I created. I created the .phtml template directly (not through the new template form on the backend) into the locale > en_US >  template > email folder. The template seems to work as the variables passed to it work and the email gets sent fine. My only problem is that now when I go into the management > Transactional Emails > New Template, the page crashes. The dropdown is empty and everything after it does't get rendered.

I think it might have something to do with the way I'm loading the template in the modules config.xml. When I remove the reference to the template the problem goes away. Put the reference back in and the form crashes..

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Optimise_Requestcallback>
      <version>0.1.9</version>
    </Optimise_Requestcallback>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <requestcallback>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Optimise_Requestcallback</module>
          <frontName>request-callback</frontName>
        </args>
      </requestcallback>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <requestcallback>
          <file>optimise.xml</file>
        </requestcallback>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <requestcallback_template translate="label" module="requestcallback">
                <label>Optimise RequestCallback</label>
                <file>requestcallback_template.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </requestcallback_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
</config>
```

Here is how I send the email:

```
public function sendemailAction() {


    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->loadDefault('requestcallback_template');


    $emailTemplateVariables = array();

    //Fetch submited params
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $subjectOfMail = "Request a Callback from the Puji Website<br /><br />Product = " . $params['product'] . "<br />Name = " . $params['name'] . "<br />Email = " . $params['email'] . "<br />Telephone = " . $params['telephone'] . "<br />Message = " . $params['comment'];

    $emailTemplateVariables['body'] = $subjectOfMail;


    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($params['name']);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($params['email']);

    try {
        $emailTemplate->send('billy@optimiseweb.co.uk', 'Sales', $emailTemplateVariables);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Thank you! We will contact you very soon.');
    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    //Redirect back to index action of (this) activecodeline-simplecontact controller
    $this->_redirect('request-callback/');
}
```

And the template itself probably couldn't be any simpler!

```
<!--@subject Request a Callback from the Puji Website @-->

{{var body}}
```

Can anyone see an issue here that would cause the New template form to crash?

Answer (score 0):

There can be various reasons, but first check `config.xml` file for each custom module, one-by-one.

There must be one module, where you will find code like:

`module="[some-module-name-here]"`

Try removing this code one-by-one and reload the transactional e-mail template form again.

I am sure, it will solve the problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.  The question suggests there's something wrong with the *email template*, **not** the modules.

Comment: But problem is due to some module's setup.

I have faced similar problem 3-4 times.